# Inverter: High- and low-side MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, inverter, mosfet-driver

The gate leg of the mosfet in my working inverter suddenly started to short circuit. There are 4 mosfets, 2 high side and 2 low side. There are 2 IR2106 mosfet drivers.

The name of the integrated circuit that controls the mosfet driver circuits is SG3524. I measured the outputs of this IC and the PWMs are as they should be.

I tried to draw the connection diagram of the circuit in the picture below.

The signal goes from the LO leg to the gate, but the signal does not go from the HO legs of both drivers to the gate and I cannot measure it.

I put the driver circuit and MOSFETs on the breadboard and I can see the HO signal on the oscilloscope, but when I put the driver in the inverter, I cannot see it. What is the reason for this? Where should I look or check?

[image]

Source: I draw it

Comment: Why are you showing a "representative" diagram and then showing another diagram that is labelled "Typical connection"? Do you not have the schematic of your design? Is this a new design you are undertaking or, it seems, is it more likely you are trying to repair something that previously worked? Maybe it never worked? Maybe you are trying to repair a friends inverter? All important details to provide.

Comment: Hello, ı put a representative diagram because the inverter which ı am working on is an old inverter so ı dont have a schematic of it. When ı check the the mosfet connection ı realized that the picture 2 is the same as inverter that is why ı put a representative picture. Yes ı am trying to repair. The inverter was working but suddenly this issue occured. @Andyaka

Comment: Please use regular I instead of dotless ı for readability in English.

Comment: Hello Sir, when I put the driver into the inverter I can not measure the HO pin through the gate but ı can see it when I put it into a seperate breadboard. What should I do ?        @Tim Williams